# Crear directorio con nombre de usuario y archivo index.php en él, cada vez que un usuario se registra

Tags: php

¿Cómo se hace para que cuando un usuario se registre, se cree automáticamente un directorio con el nombre del usuario y un archivo index.php en su interior?

Ejemplo:
Nombre: Paco

Y al registrarse que en el directorio raiz se cree:
www.dominio.com/**paco/index.php**

¡Saludos y gracias!

Comment: suena a muy pero muy mala idea.. nos contas porque queres hacer esto?

Comment: coincido, suena a muy mala idea, pero si necesitas hacerlo lo ideal sería que probaras con "exec".

Comment: Es muy mala idea, por que no en vez de eso utilizas variables $_SESSION para mostrar datos personalizados para cada usuario?

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. El objetivo es que cada usuario pueda tener su propia url. No valdría lo de las session, ya que cualquiera que quiera acceder a esa url, no podría ya que tendría que ser usuario. ¿no? Después en cada index.php ya habría la consulta correspondiente para mostrar la información del usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Hola voy a responder tu pregunta, pero te aclaro que esta abriendo un agujero de seguridad que te va a costar cerrar, estoy de acuerdo con los demas que no es una buena idea

```
<?php
// Estructura de la carpeta deseada
$estructura = './nivel1/nivel2/nivel3/';

// Para crear una estructura anidada se debe especificar
// el parámetro $recursive en mkdir().

if(!mkdir($estructura, 0777, true)) {
    die('Fallo al crear las carpetas...');
}

?>
```